# Doctrine DQL - Select column alias added as new record

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a user entity linked to a user profile entity.

I need to be able to concatenate a users first name and last name for filtering purposes.

This is roughly how my query looks like :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('users');
$qb
    ->addSelect('users')
    ->innerJoin('users.profile', 'profile')
    ->addSelect('profile')
    ->addSelect('CONCAT(profile.firstName, \' \', profile.lastName) AS fullName')
;
```

I would expect the fullname to be treated as a user property, or profile, but instead i get the fullName as a whole new record in the results:

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 5
    [username] => admin
    [profile] => Array (
        [firstName] => John
        [lastName] => Doe
    )
), 
[fullName] => John Doe
```

I tried aliasing the column as "users.fullName" but that gives me an error.

**[Syntax Error] line 0, col 87: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got '.'**

What is the proper way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to match the `fullName` in the query or later in PHP?

Comment: Use [native query instead](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html) then map the field to the class properties using the ResultSetMapping.

Comment: lxg: Yes, i will need to do a match in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you provide the whole list of needed columns in select method:

```
    ->select("user.id, user.username, CONCAT(profile.firstName, ' ', profile.lastName) AS fullName")
```

And you should receive proper assoc array.

Remember to add proper where clause:

```
    ->where("CONCAT(profile.firstName, ' ', profile.lastName) LIKE :name")
    ->setParameter('name', '%' . $name . '%')
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
While this does work, i'd prefer ideally to keep the default Doctrine behavior and return entities collections.
Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: I you prefer to return entites collection there is no simple way of mapping custom database property to entity result.

Comment: Ok, i guess the easiest thing there add a where condition with the concatenated values instead of loading it as an additionnal field.

Thanks for your help.